# Indian passport holder with valid US F1 visa traveling to Canada by road with a pet dog

Tags: usa, canada, f1-visas, pets

I want to travel to Toronto, Canada from Boston, USA by road with my 2 and half year old Siberian Husky. I wanted to understand what documents do I need for myself as a F1 visa holder and my dog to cross the border.

Comment: http://www.inspection.gc.ca/animals/terrestrial-animals/imports/policies/live-animals/pets/dogs/eng/1331876172009/1331876307796

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enter Canada as a temporary visitor, you need your passport and a [visa for Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-result.asp?q2=no&country=IN&result=1). A US visa alone will not permit you to enter Canada. (And to expedite your return to the US, because you're in F1 status, you should bring your I-94 and I-20.)

Your *dog* needs a current rabies certificate, written in English or French, or EU pet passport. Canada's complete [requirements for importing your dog](http://www.inspection.gc.ca/animals/terrestrial-animals/imports/policies/live-animals/pets/dogs/eng/1331876172009/1331876307796) (of which this is but the most important of them) are listed on their web site.

> Dogs may enter Canada if they are accompanied by a rabies vaccination
>   certificate.
>
> ### Rabies Vaccination Certificate
>
> The European Union pet passport is an acceptable alternative to the
>   rabies vaccination certificate as long as all the required elements
>   outlined below are included.
>
> #### The rabies vaccination certificate must:
>
> - be written in English or French;
> - be issued and signed by a licensed veterinarian;
> - identify the animal (breed, sex, colour, and weight);
> - state that the animal is vaccinated against rabies;
> - indicate the date of vaccination;
> - indicate the trade name and the serial number of the licensed vaccine; and
> - specify the duration of immunity (otherwise, it will be considered valid for one year from the date of vaccination).
>
> ### Animals That Do Not Meet Canadian Rabies Import Requirements
>
> If a dog does not meet the Canadian rabies import requirements, owners
>   will be required, at their own expense, to:
>
> - have the animal vaccinated against rabies within a specified period of time; and
> - provide the vaccination record to a Canadian Food Inspection Agency office.
>
> Please note that the option of rabies vaccination upon arrival is not
>   available for dogs less than 8 months of age imported under the
>   commercial category.